# How to detect data binding completed in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

When I select an item on my treeview, there is a notable time gap from my viewmodel class being instantiated to the view refreshing and the treeview node being hi-lit.

I need to show a wait cursor during this time - I've tried wrapping the code that instantiates my viewmodel class, but the cursor is back to an arrow a couple of seconds before the whole data binding seems to finish and the node gets hi-lit.  Is there some event that tells me when the binding is finished, or when the node is hi-lit ?

This is nothing to do with expanding nodes, simply selecting top-level nodes.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11):

The Loaded event on the desired TreeView control will happen after all of the bindings have been set up. I think it happens before everything has been drawn though so it might not be exactly what you need.

Comment: absolutely agree, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx

Comment: The link to the blog seems to have moved to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mikehillberg/the-loaded-event-and-the-initialized-event

Answer (score 8):

You can get notified when the target or when the source is updated.

```
<TreeViewItem>
    <TextBlock Name="NameText"
      Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
      TargetUpdated="OnTargetUpdated"/>
</TreeViewItem>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a "hang" when this gap occurs? Maybe you need to put the heavy logic on a separate thread or simply use IsAsync property of the Binding class.
You may also want to take a look at Priority Binding. [Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-priority-bindings) is a pretty good article on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the OnContentRendered for Window control.

Answer (score 0):

in my cases, when i remove (IsAsync=True) property, ContentRendered Method immediately catch end of render.

check IsAsync property of your control.