# When does the data get bound and how to speed it up?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm stepping through the code and I see that in the constructor of my view, I set *DataContext* to a new instance of my view model. Stepping into it, I can see that the field *Thingies* is set. Stepping out back to the view's constructor, I can verify that, indeed, the property of the view model is set and the count of the elements is correct.

Then... (let's get back to this spot in a second)

Finally, I can see the rendered GUI where the data produced by the view model is shown just as supposed to. Everything has worked out as supposed to. Now, I only need to set the first row of the grid as selected, which shouldn't be a problem, because I know that the data is there (verified by a step-in to model view's constructor, watch on data context's fields and the actual window's contents).

But nooo... (now, let's get back to the aforementioned spot)

When I investigate the grid's *DataItems* property, while still in the constructor, I discover that there's zero elements in it. Since I've seen those on the screen, I know they must get there somehow **but**, apparently, the binding of the view model's property *Thingies* takes place **after** the constructor's run.

I'd like to enforce the binding to take place **while still in the constructor** (if that's the most appropriate approach). As the plan B, I'm thinking about reacting to some event (like *Blopp_OnDataBound(...)* or something) but I haven't found anything except [target being updated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24434226/1525840). I've put *TargetUpdated="TheGriddy_OnTargetUpdated"* next to the data source's binding but the method doesn't invoke.

NB. Even though I'm doing this on a specific control, I'm convinced that the question is generally applicable to any control as it's about the XAML/WPF's data binding paradigm. Correct me if I'm wrong. (I'm on Infragistics' *XamDataGrid* but the behavior is most likely reproduceable for the good, old, plain *DataGrid*.)

As requested, I'm also providing a small sample, which I chose not to before, as I thought it wasn't of any help. I stand corrected.

```
public MyView()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = new MyViewModel();

  if (xamDataGrid.DataSource != null)
    throw new HappyException("yes!");
}

private void SomeMethod()
{
  if (xamDataGrid.DataSource != null)
    throw new HappyException("yes!");
}
```

The problem is that the exception is never thrown in the constructor but is 
in the method. The data source is set as we bind, so the binding must occur after the constructor's been run, right?

I need to select the first row. That can be done when the first row exists...

Comment: I read your question twice, but I'm still unable to understand the situation in all its complexity. I know it's a lot of work, but an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help here.

Comment: Also, I think a code snippet with some comments will help to understand your question - we write code not literature :-)

Comment: @Heinzi I've added some sample. Perhaps it'll help clarify my question.

Comment: @derape As requested. Enjoy.   :)

Answer (score 0):

Data binding seems to happen during the `LayoutUpdated` event when the window is first shown. I think the plan B is the only possible way so far. Use the `TargetUpdated` event as mentioned in the [How to detect data binding completed in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825097/how-to-detect-data-binding-completed-in-wpf/24434226#24434226) thread, but note that you need to **explicitly** enable `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` otherwise it will not fire (as you already have seen).

Comment: How would you say *TargetUpdated* relates to *Loaded* (if I'm doing the same stuff there, of course)? Would it be less preferred? I'll be only performing the operation upon the user loading in the view, not while they'll be working with it later on.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Well, you can use Loaded of course, but TargetUpdated IMO is better because it would fire on every rebind (if you do so of course). But if that's all you need, sure use Loaded - TargetUpdated fires first, then Loaded.