# In WPF, is there a "render complete" event?

Tags: wpf

In WPF, When I load a wrap panel with a lot of elements, the window stalls for a while before showing the content. I would like to add a wait hint but I could not find a way to detect when the wrap panel completes rendering.

I have tried "loaded", "sizechanged", "initialized" without success. Has anyone got any idea on this issue ?

Many thanks !

Comment: It's on the same thread so you don't need an event. It finishes when your code reaches line after the line that loads the data.

Comment: @FCin Thank you. But it acts not like that. After loading e.g, 200 elements in the wrappanel, the code-behind returns, the window stalls, and it takes about 1~2 seconds before the window gets back to life again.

Comment: Probably binding is still happening, You can check if the thread is ApplicationIdle to tell when the processing is done.

Comment: Handle the Loaded event of the last element in the WrapPanel?

Comment: This seems to be a massive bug in WPF. You can change the DispatcherPriority of UI rendering so that it does lazy loading and doesn't lock the screen up, but if you do this, there is no way to know when the UI has completed rendering.

Comment: see this answer.
in my cases, it run very well https://stackoverflow.com/a/63259032/7682713

Answer (score 18):

At the start of rendering call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` with the Dispatcher Priority of `ContextIdle`.

My start of rendering just happened to be a treeview selected item change event, but this could be any event that you need to wait for the UI to finish updating.

```
    private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => DoSomething()), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
       //This will get called after the UI is complete rendering
    }
```

Comment: I have a ItemsControl that I populate with a lot of items and it takes time. Using this together with ItemsControl's OnSizeChanged works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Yes, use the Window.ContentRendered [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.contentrendered?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Didn't know that one. nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can override the OnRender method to detect when rendering is complete.

To push all events call Dispatcher.DoEvents() where DoEvents is implemented as an extension method:

```
public static class DispatcherExtensions
{
    public static void DoEvents(this Dispatcher dispatcher, DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Background)
    {
        DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
        DispatcherOperation dispatcherOperation = dispatcher.BeginInvoke(priority, (Action<DispatcherFrame>)ExitFrame, frame);
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);

       if (dispatcherOperation.Status != DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed)
           dispatcherOperation.Abort();
   }

    private static void ExitFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
    {
        frame.Continue = false;
    }

    public static void Flush(this Dispatcher dispatcher, DispatcherPriority priority)
    {
        dispatcher.Invoke(()=> { }, priority);
    }
```

}

In retrospect I think it's a terrible idea to use this because it can cause hard to solve bugs.

```
// this shows how bad it is to call Flush or DoEvents
int clicker = 0;
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (clicker != 0)
    {
        // This is reachable... // Could be skipped for DispatcherPriority.Render but then again for render it seems to freeze sometimes.
    }
    clicker++;
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    this.Dispatcher.Flush(DispatcherPriority.Input);

    //this.Dispatcher.DoEvents(DispatcherPriority.Render);
    //this.Dispatcher.DoEvents(DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
    //this.Dispatcher.DoEvents(DispatcherPriority.Input);
    //this.Dispatcher.DoEvents(DispatcherPriority.Background);
    clicker--;
}
```